# why rmdir can work well when delete cgroup directory but rm -rf can not?

Tags: rm, cgroups

Here is a cgroup tree. Root node is demo and it has only one child

```
demo/
├── cgroup.clone_children
├── cgroup.procs
├── cgroup.sane_behavior
├── child
│   ├── cgroup.clone_children
│   ├── cgroup.procs
│   ├── notify_on_release
│   ├── pool_size
│   └── tasks
├── notify_on_release
├── pool_size
├── release_agent
└── tasks
```

try to delete the child node with rm -rf hit error but rmdir work well

```
[root@iZ8vbf3rrty84cddfc7w8mZ cgroup]# rm -rf demo/child/
rm: cannot remove ‘demo/child/cgroup.procs’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘demo/child/tasks’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘demo/child/pool_size’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘demo/child/notify_on_release’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘demo/child/cgroup.clone_children’: Operation not permitted
[root@iZ8vbf3rrty84cddfc7w8mZ cgroup]#
[root@iZ8vbf3rrty84cddfc7w8mZ cgroup]# rmdir demo/child/
[root@iZ8vbf3rrty84cddfc7w8mZ cgroup]#
```

Why rmdir can but rm -rf can not work here

Answer (score 4):

`rm -rf` deletes all the files and then the directory. `rmdir` just deletes the directory.

It makes no sense to delete a single file like `pool_size` from a cgroup. What would that *do*? But it does make sense to delete a cgroup. `rm -rf` doesn't know this, since fake files look the same as real files.

In fact it's the opposite of real files: you can't delete a real directory until it's got no files in it, but you have to delete this particular fake directory while it has files in it.

That's why.

Answer (score 0):

The `rm` command also removes all files (which probably cannot be done for the [cgroups pseudo file system](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html)).

The `rmdir` command removes the directory if all files are removed.

I guess it does not consider a pseudo file system as a file. So it can go through.

I'm not sure if that is a bug.